# How to exclude beans/packages from Spring AOP processing scope

Tags: java, spring, jmx, spring-aop, spring-integration

How to exclude beans, or packages from **Spring AOP** processing scope?

I encountered this, while fixing **Spring Integration JMX** support issue on **JBoss**.

As a development environment, we are using **Spring 3.2.0.RELEASE**, **Spring Integration 2.2.0.RELEASE** and **Jboss AS 7.1.1**.

When enabling **Spring Integration JMX**, you are actually creating **IntegrationMBeanExporter**, which extracts all **Spring Integration** related beans from the underlying **ApplicationContext** and creates appropriate managed **MBeans**. For assigning created **MBeans** to server **MBeanServer** required, which must be defined in **ApplicationContext**, which is generally done using standard **MBeanServerFactoryBean**, which returns platform related **MBeanServer**.

The problem appeared, because we were using **Spring AOP** for some enhanced operations, and **AOP post processing mechanism** was trying to process platform **mbeanServer** like regular **bean**, validating **initial platform ClassLoader** against internal pointcuts, which it eventually failed to do.

This seems to be similar to https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9335, but with generic specifics.

So as a solution, I prevented **spring** from processing **mbeanServer** as a part ApplicationContext :

```
<bean id="jmxIntegration" scope="singleton" class="org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter">
    <property name="server" value="#{ T(org.springframework.jmx.support.JmxUtils).locateMBeanServer() }"/>
</bean>
```

This worked, but this seems to be of a more generic problem, with **AOP**.

Also interesting note is that **MBeanExporter** in spring also refers to **JmxUtils** instead of context's **MBeanServer**.

Comment: Can you post your AOP pointcut(s) from which you want to exclude beans/packages?

Comment: <aop:pointcut expression="execution(public * org.springframework.data.repository.Repository+.save*(..)) and args(incident)" id="onAfterSaveIncident"/>

But this is not a pointcut problem, this is ClassLoader validation problem in container.